# How can I start a Q&A site that does not yet exist?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there is a Q&A site that doesn't exist yet which Stack Exchange is a good format for. How can I make that site?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, an infinite amount.  Go to [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).  The World is your Oyster.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know where to look.